# tensor product of two compact induced representations

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

Suppose $A \subset A^{\prime}$ and $B \subset B^{\prime}$ are all p-adic groups, and $V_{\pi}$ is a representation of $A$; $V_{\rho}$ is a representation of $B$.

Define 
$ind_{A}^{A^{\prime}}V_{\pi}:=\{f:A^{\prime} \to V_{\pi}|\ f(aa^{\prime})=\pi(a)f(a^{\prime}), \text{and  $f$ is locally constant and has  compact support module  $A$}.\}$

Similarly, we can define $ind_{B}^{B^{\prime}}V_{\rho}$ and $ind_{A \times B}^{A^{\prime} \times B^{\prime}}(V_{\pi}\boxtimes V_{\rho})$.

Clearly, we have a map 
$ind_{A}^{A^{\prime}}V_{\pi} \boxtimes ind_{B}^{B^{\prime}}V_{\rho} \to ind_{A \times B}^{A^{\prime} \times B^{\prime}}(V_{\pi}\boxtimes V_{\rho})$. But I have difficulties to see whether the map is isomorphism. Thank you all the time.